# SwiftUI - navigationbar title animates wrong when using a vstack inside a scrollview

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I noticed strange behavior under iOS 14 today.
When you put a VStack into a ScrollView, which is located in a navigationview,
the large title animation does not work when scrolling. It just jumps and does not animate for some reason.

If you replace the VStack with a list everything works.

```
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(0..<1000) { _ in
                                Text("Foobar")
                            }
                        }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Items") 
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what exactly is causing this behavior right now.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: iOS 14 is still in beta with tons of bug including one you asked.

Comment: I am running into the exact same issue. Sorry if this isn't any help, but I also hope this is a beta bug and that it will be fixed eventually

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the latest iOS 14 Beta.